# Highcharts - Grouped Scatter? (relative to Grouped Column)

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot

I have a Grouped Column Series mapped, 3 columns in a group.
I would like to add scatter points over each of the three columns within each group.

Each scatter point would be centered over each column in the group.

Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with this type of functionality?

Best,
Stu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this isn't directly supported, but possible to achieve, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/229/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['01/02/2012','01/03/2012','01/04/2012','01/05/2012','01/06/2012','01/07/2012']
    },

    series: [{
        type:'column',
        data: [3,4,5]        
    },{
        type:'column',
        data: [5,4,2]        
    },{
        type:'column',
        data: [3,1,5]        
    },{
        type:'scatter',
        data: [{
            x: -0.2,   
            y: 1
        },{
            x: 0,   
            y: 3
        },{
            x: 0.2,   
            y: 2
        }]        
    }]
});
```

Comment: excellent, thank you. i would have never guessed to start at -0.2 and then increment .2 for each column within a group. works great!